# CASTING Session.Query() in Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

How and What type should I cast `result` to `User` or `Role` or `Permission`?

A User has Roles and A Role has Permissions

```
var result = session.Query<User>()
                    .Where(c => c.UserName == userName)
                    .FetchMany(c => c.Roles)
                    .ThenFetchMany(o => o.Permissions);
```

Comment: I will be cast to the type 'User'

Answer (score 2):

Methods like `Fetch` (for simple properties) and `FetchMany`(for collections properties) method will create an `join` in the t-sql query executed by nhibernate and fill the property up after the execution. It will avoid the Lazy Loading to the property. But after you call these methods, you still have an `IQueryable<User>` (in your case), because you started with it.

To get a result (or make a cast), depend of how you concrete your query linq, for sample:

For a `List<User>`, you could call `ToList()`:

```
var result = session.Query<User>()
                    .Where(c => c.UserName == userName)
                    .FetchMany(c => c.Roles)
                    .ThenFetchMany(o => o.Permissions)
                    .ToList();

// and you could loop it:
foreach (var user in result)
{
      // code...
}
```

For a single `User` object, you could call `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var result = session.Query<User>()
                    .Where(c => c.UserName == userName)
                    .FetchMany(c => c.Roles)
                    .ThenFetchMany(o => o.Permissions)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

// and you could use this User object, 
// but make sure it is not null 
if (result != null)
{
   // code...
}
```

You also can change the output using the `Select()` to a `DTO` object, an anonnymous object, an specific value, etc. For sample, to return an anonymous object (generally to use in a local scope and execute a simple query), using `Select()` method.

```
var result = session.Query<User>()
                    .Where(c => c.UserName == userName)
                    .FetchMany(c => c.Roles)
                    .ThenFetchMany(o => o.Permissions)
                    .Select(u => new { u.Id, u.UserName })
                    .ToList(); // or FirstOrDefault();
```